Leaky tiled shower bench
Hoping for some insight here.  Walk-in shower built in 2019, had sitting bench built in per our request.  After some time (1 year?) we noticed water leaking thru ceiling of laundry room directly below shower upstairs.  Determined that the grout in edge of bench in shower had cracked, and water was leaking thru crack and down inside of bench.  I re-grouted edge and sealed it with grout seal ... told wife "let's just not sit on the bench, ok?"
Well my fat ass sat on the bench and it's happened again.  Looking for recs on how to:

BEST fix for a permanent solution.
At what hopefully is not too high of a cost.

Have quote from a reputable tile guy ... $3800 (labor/materials) to re-tile bench and "REMOVE/REPLACE 18 TILES W/ PROPER WATERPROOFING" OR ...  $1650 (labor only) for install of 2 pieces of countertop that we procure from counter fabricator (idea is instead of re-tiling just put one large piece of counter on top of bench and another on side of bench, seal all edges for watertight fix)
I have no idea if proper (or any) waterproofing membrane was used.  I suspect not.  Re-grouting or some freaking flex-seal seems cheapest but not optimal and I am willing to spend $ for a proper fix.  Any advice is appreciated!

Welcome to [diy.se], please take [tour]. I recommend an [edit] to remove the pricing and replace it with something generic like "install coutertop for about 1/2 the price". Pricing is explicitly off topic because it varies so much from place to place and even month to month.
